# DSpace and Physical Separation of Documents

Tags: java, api, document-repository, dspace

I'm looking for a document repository that supports physical data separation. I was looking into Open Text's [LiveLink](http://www.opentext.com/), but that price range is out of my league. I just started looking into [DSpace](http://www.dspace.org/)! Its free and open source and works with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

I'm really trying to figure out if DSpace supports physically separating the data. I guess I would create multiple DSpace Communities, and I want the documents for each Community store on different mounts. Is this possible? Or is there a better way?

Also, I wont be using DSpace's front end. The User will not even know DSpace is storing the docs. I will build my own front-end and use Java to talk to DSpace. Does anyone know a good Java API Wrappers for DSpace.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a pretty long time after you asked the question, so not sure if it's of any use to you.

DSpace currently does not support storing different parts of the data on different partitions, although your asset store can be located on its own partition separate from the database and the application.  You may get want you need from the new [DuraSpace](http://www.duraspace.org/) application which deals with synchronising your data to the cloud.

In terms of Java APIs, DSpace supports [SWORD 1.3](http://swordapp.org/) which is a deposit-only protocol, and a lightweight implementation of WebDAV with SOAP.  Other than that, it's somewhat lacking.  If you are looking for a real back-end repository with good web services you might look at [Fedora](http://www.fedora-commons.org) which is a pure back end, with no native UI, and probably more suited to your needs.  DSpace and Fedora are both part of the DuraSpace organisation so you can probably benefit from that also.  I'm not knowledgeable enough about the way that Fedora stores data to say whether you can physically separate the storage, though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: DuraCloud seems like a nice service, but not quite what I'm looking for. But thank you so much for this tip on SWORD and I'll try moving the asset store to its own partition to see if it does what I need. If it works, I'll mark it as correct answer, but this is all very good information. Oh and your link for FedoraCommons needs to be updated. http://fedora-commons.org/  but thank you!

Comment: Ah, ok, I did the Fedora link from memory :)  To switch the assetstore to its own partition you just need the partition mounted and then to specify the assetstore directory config option in dspace.cfg.